# Ordering values

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to order items based on an attribute value:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Question">
    <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="@Value"></xsl:sort>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

This does order them, but I could have values like 1,2,3, ... 10, 11, ... 20 and it will order them 1,10,11, ... 2,20... 3. etc.
I could also have values like 1.A, 1.B, 2.A, 2.B etc.

How can I order these values to take into account the numeric content and the alphabetic, in that priority?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know that every question has a multi-part number, you could handle them with two `<xsl:sort>` instructions:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Question">
  <xsl:sort select="substring-before(@Value, '.')" data-type="number" />
  <xsl:sort select="substring-after(@Value, '.')" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

If some of the numbers might have multiple parts and some not, I guess the best thing to do is:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Question">
  <xsl:sort select="substring-before(concat(@Value, '.'), '.')" data-type="number" />
  <xsl:sort select="substring-after(@Value, '.')" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

The extra `concat(@Value, '.')` adds a '`.`' to the end of the value so that the `substring-before()` always gets the number.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort in numeric order using the [`data-type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#sorting) attribute:

```
<xsl:sort order="ascending" select="@Value" data-type="number"></xsl:sort>
```

The built-in sort function does not have support for more complex ordering (such as the multipart keys you mention).

Answer (score 0):

For [sorting](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_sort.asp) numbers you can use this:

```
<xsl:template match="employees">
  <xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:sort select="salary" data-type="number"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that the `data-type` attribute is used [here](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/07/03/transform.html). For values like values like 1.A, 1.B, 2.A, 2.B you are back to text again and will have to resort to clever stuff that probably resorts to ugly nesting. Do consider the `xsl:number` [element](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_number.asp) which can be used in interesting ways.